# What is the decompiled (C) code construct of this assembly x86 code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, decompiling

This code compares every char of a string (located at `ebp+arg_0`) with different constants (ASCII chars) like 'I', 'o' and 'S'. I guess, based on other code parts, this code is originally written in C.

[image: assembly]

This compare-code-part looks very inefficient to. **My question**, how do you think this code will look in C? What code construct was used originally? my thoughts so far

- It's not a **for loop**. Because i don't see any upward jump and stop-condition.
- It's not a while/case/switch code construct
- My best guess is that this are a lot of consecutive if/else statements. 
  Can you help?

*Yes it's part of a challenge, i already have the flag/solution, no worries about that. Just trying to better understand the code.*

Comment: If this is some kind of crackme then it shouldn't be efficient. The whole point of crackmes is to confuse a researcher.

Comment: You can use a timing attack against this to find the correct password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's not a for loop. Because i don't see any upward jump and stop-condition.

Correct.

> It's not a while/case/switch code constuct

It can't be, it compares different indicies of the array.

> My best guess is that this are a lot of consecutive if/elses. Can you help?

Looks like it could be this code:

```
void f(const char* arg_0) {
    if(arg_0[4] == 'I' && arg_0[5] == 'o' && arg_0[6] == 'S') {
        printf("Gratz man :)");
        exit(0); //noreturn, hence your control flow ends here in the assembly
    }
    puts("Wrong password"); // Or `printf("Wrong password\n");` which gets optimized to `puts`
    // leave, retn
}
```

[This is how gcc compiles it without optimizations](https://godbolt.org/z/My8v0o):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Gratz man :)"
.LC1:
        .string "Wrong password"
f(char const*):
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 8
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        add     eax, 4
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]
        cmp     al, 73
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        add     eax, 5
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]
        cmp     al, 111
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        add     eax, 6
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]
        cmp     al, 83
        jne     .L2
        sub     esp, 12
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        add     esp, 16
        sub     esp, 12
        push    0
        call    exit
.L2:
        sub     esp, 12
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    puts
        add     esp, 16
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

Looks very similar to your disassembled code.

> This compare-code-part looks very inefficient

Looks like it was compiled without optimizations. With optimizations enabled, [gcc compiled the code to](https://godbolt.org/z/8snTiD):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Gratz man :)"
.LC1:
        .string "Wrong password"
f(char const*):
        sub     esp, 12
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+16]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [eax+4], 73
        jne     .L2
        cmp     BYTE PTR [eax+5], 111
        je      .L5
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+16], OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        add     esp, 12
        jmp     puts
.L5:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [eax+6], 83
        jne     .L2
        sub     esp, 12
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp], 0
        call    exit
```

Not sure why gcc decided to jump down and back up again instead of a straight line of `jne`s. Also, the `ret` is gone, your `printf` got tail-call-optimized, i.e. a `jmp printf` istead of a `call printf` followed by a `ret`.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed really close! Thanks for your support!

Comment: `puts` adds a newline, `printf` doesn't.  (And gcc doesn't look for the optimization of using `fputs(str, stdout)` for constant strings that don't end with newline.)  Anyway, the asm uses puts, it would be clearest to just use puts.  Anyway, missing `"\n"` is why your gcc version isn't getting optimized to puts.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I've edited it to use puts. I didn't realize `puts` appends a newline.

Comment: I probably wouldn't remember that about `puts` as easily if it wasn't for looking at compiler asm output and finding out about that optimization :P  Modern gcc can even handle `printf("%s\n", "string")`, even for cases where `"string"` is a variable with compile-time constant value after constant-propagation.  But I *do* actually type `puts` sometimes (especially in toy / experiment code), because it has a shorter name than printf, because it appends a \n that I won't have to type, and because it's immune to format-string vulnerabilities for outputting a runtime variable string.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument (`arg_0`) is a pointer to the given password string, e.g., `const char *arg_0`. This pointer (the address of the first character) is loaded into the `eax` register (`mov eax, [ebp+arg_0]`), and then the index of the current character is added to advance it to that index (`add eax, 4` etc.). The single byte at that address is then loaded into `eax` (`movzx eax, byte ptr [eax]`).

Then that byte/character is compared against the correct one (`cmp eax, 'I'`, etc). If the result is not zero (i.e., if they are not equal), the program jumps to the "Wrong password" branch (`jnz` - jump if not zero), otherwise it continues on to the next comparison (and ultimately success).

The nearest direct C equivalent would therefore be something like:

```
void check(const char *arg_0) {
    // presumably comparisons 0-3 are omitted
    if (arg_0[4] != 'I') goto fail;
    if (arg_0[5] != 'o') goto fail;
    if (arg_0[6] != 'S') goto fail;
    printf("Gratz man :)");
    exit(0);
fail:
    puts("Wrong password");
}
```

(Of course the actual C code is unlikely to have looked like this, since the `goto fail` arrangement is not typical.)

Comment: Thanks! When i decompile this the assembly code looks almost identical.